# Create patch of changes introduced by git branch before merging to master

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

In gitlab CI for merge requests I want to create file `changes.diff` that summarizes changes introduced by this merge request.

Some context:
I have CI that verifies (using clang-format-diff) if merge request (MR) introduces some formatting deviations from `.clang-format` style and looks for new `#if 0`. Reformatting and cleaning whole project is on wishlist, but won't happen soon. But when we are on the bottom, it is good idea to at least stop digging.
So far I have following script:

```
oldrev=$(git rev-list HEAD --grep="Merge branch '.*' into 'master'" |head -n1)
newrev=${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_SOURCE_BRANCH_SHA:-$(git rev-parse HEAD)}

# 1 Find what files changed, consider only added, copied, modified (ACM), not removed, moved
# 2 ignore files with extensions that suggest its not code
files=$(git  diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only --diff-filter=ACM -r $oldrev $newrev | egrep "\.(c|cpp|cxx|cc|h|hpp|ipp|tpp)$")
if [[ -z "${files}" ]]; then
    echo "nothing interesting changed"
    exit 0
fi

echo "Changed files:"
echo $files

echo $files | xargs  git  diff  -U0 --no-color $oldrev $newrev --  > changes.diff
```

This works fine in simple cases:

- topic branch was forked from master
- there were no merges from master to topic (sometimes necessary for conflict resolution before merge to master)

If either of those don't hold, `changes.diff` starts holding changes introduced by other MRs. How can I improve this script?